# Installing out side light

Tags: electrical

I am installing a outside light but have 3 wires coming to the light, red, black and white and only black white and green from the new light, How do I hook this up

Comment: Was there a light there before? How was it connected?

Comment: If the new light has a green wire, this suggests it may need a ground/earth connection for safety. I'd read the manufacturers installation instructions carefully to check this point.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are pretty good that the red wire is just extra (or the black wire). The two most common types of wire for lighting and outlets come in 2 and 3 wire varieties, so sometimes you have an extra wire. Try to hook up just the white and black (green to ground), and see if it works.  If not, swap the black for red.

Of course if you have a voltage tester, you can check the white/black and white/red pairs for voltage *before* hooking up the light.

There's a small chance that one of the red or black wires has constant voltage and the other is switched, so use a voltage detector and make sure *all* the power is off before splicing anything.

Answer (score 1):

could look at the back side of the switch inside that is used to control the light. either the black or the red would be connected to the switch, and the white should just be connected to itself and running from the supply to the light. there will probably be either the black or red, whichever isnt connected to the switch, not connected to anything, or connected to ground.

Comment: or connected to something else, but true, that a visual inspection of the switch will yield some useful information